# Windows Phone 8 Push Notification :: Can I Bind Same push channel to Toast and Tile

Tags: windows-phone-8

Following is the code for WP8 push notification.

```
HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

                // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

                // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

                pushChannel.Open();

                // Bind this new channel for toast events.
                pushChannel.BindToShellToast();
                pushChannel.BindToShellTile();
```

As you can see in above code I am binding pushChannel to **shellToast as well as shellTile**.  I want to know is it valid or not? since I haven't got any doc on msdn regarding this. **If it is possible and server sends any of the notifications will it be shown properly?**
Please give your valuable feedback on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible and it is the right way to do it. One app, one channel, no matter how many kinds of push notifications you use.